# Multiple Derived Classes in boost python using pure virtual function

Tags: c++, boost-python, pure-virtual

how to use pure virtual function for Multiple inhertiance by using boost python. Error i got  are that 'Derived1' cannot instaniate abstract class. and 'Derived2' cannot instantiate abstract class. this code is working if there is only one derived class but more than one derived classs its not working. thanks for help.

```
class Base
{
  public:
   virtual int test1(int a,int b) = 0;
   virtual int test2 (int c, int d) = 0;
   virtual ~Base() {}
 };

class Derived1
  : public Base
 {
   public:
   int test1(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
};

class Derived2
 : public Base
{
  public:
  int test2(int c, int d) { return c+d; }
};
struct BaseWrap
  : Base, python::wrapper<Base>
{
  int test1(int a , int b) 
  {
     return this->get_override("test")(a, b);
   }
  int test2(int c ,int d)
   {
     return this->get_override("test")(c, d);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) 
{
  python::class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base")
   .def("test1", python::pure_virtual(&BaseWrap::test1))
   .def("test2", python::pure_virtual(&BaseWrap::test2))
   ;

  python::class_<Derived1, python::bases<Base> >("Derived1")
   .def("test1", &Derived1::test1)
   ;

   python::class_<Derived2, python::bases<Base> >("Derived2")
   .def("test2", &Derived2::test2)
   ;   
}
```

Comment: what exactly errors are?

Comment: Errors are error C2259: 'Derived1' : cannot instantiate abstract class              error C2259: 'Derived2' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Comment: "this code is working if there is only one derived class" Does this mean that you can have the same exact definition for `Base`, have the same exact definition for `Derived1`, but take out the definition for `Derived2`, and keep the definition for `BaseWrap`, and it works?

Comment: yes if there in only one pure virtual function and one derived class then its works. but 2 pure virtual function and they implemented in different derived classes, then i got error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages indicate that neither `Derived1` nor `Derived2` can be instantiated, as they are abstract classes:

- `Derived1` has a pure virtual function: `int Base::test2(int, int)`.
- `Derived2` has a pure virtual function: `int Base::test1(int, int)`.

When either of these are exposed via `boost::python::class_`, a compiler error should occur. [`class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec)'s `HeldType` defaults to the type being exposed, and the `HeldType` is constructed within a Python object.  Hence, `python::class_<Derived1, ...>` will instantiate Boost.Python templates that attempt to create an object with a dynamic type of `Derived1`, resulting in the compiler error.

This error does not present itself with `BaseWrap`, as `BaseWrap` implements all pure virtual functions.  The `boost::python::pure_virtual()` function specifies that Boost.Python will raise a "pure virtual called" exception during dispatch if the function has not been overridden in either C++ or Python.